# Add custom ggplot legend

Tags: r, ggplot2, legend

I'm trying to add a custom legend to my ggplot, similar to the examples in: http://docs.ggplot2.org/0.9.2.1/scale_gradientn.html

I want the bars in the plot to be colored according to the `df$col` column and for that reason I'm using `scale_fill_manual` with `values = coloursv`.

```
set.seed(1)
df <- data.frame(log10.p.value = -10*log10(runif(10,0,1)), y = letters[1:10], col = rep("#E0E0FF",10), stringsAsFactors = F)
#specify color by log10.p.value
df$col[which(df$log10.p.value > 2)] <- "#EBCCD6"
df$col[which(df$log10.p.value > 4)] <- "#E09898"
df$col[which(df$log10.p.value > 6)] <- "#C74747"
df$col[which(df$log10.p.value > 8)] <- "#B20000"
#truncate bars
df$log10.p.value[which(df$log10.p.value > 10)] <- 10
coloursv <- df$col
names(coloursv) <- df$col
p <- ggplot(df, aes(y=log10.p.value,x=y,fill=as.factor(col)))+
  geom_bar(stat="identity",width=0.2) +
  scale_y_continuous(limits=c(0,10)) +
  theme(axis.text=element_text(size=10)) +
  scale_fill_manual(values = coloursv)+coord_flip()+
  scale_fill_gradientn(colours=c("#EBCCD6","#E09898","#C74747","#B20000","#E0E0FF"),
                        breaks=c(-4,-3,-2,-1,0),guide="colorbar",labels=c(2,4,6,8,10))
```

And getting nothing:

[image]

Answer (score 2):

You're not getting a legend, because you have `scale_fill_manual(values = coloursv,guide=F)` and `guide=F` prevents a fill legend from being shown.

On the other hand, `scale_color_gradientn` sets a color aesthetic, but you don't have a color aesthetic in your plot. You probably meant `scale_fill_gradient` here (in which case you wouldn't want to also have `scale_fill_manual`). However, even if you switch this statement to `scale_fill_manual`, you've set the breaks to be at values that are outside the range of the values in your data (breaks range from -4 to 0, but data ranges from 0.4 to 10).

Adding `df$col` doesn't set the colors that get plotted. It just creates a categorical variable with different category values in different ranges of `log10.p.value`. You could have called the category values anything, and ggplot2 has a default color palette that's the same regardless of the category names and depends only on the number of categories. If you want categorical values, you can instead use the cut function as shown below.

Here are a few examples to illustrate various fill options and legends:

```
# Create log10.p.value categories
df$log10.p.value.cat = cut(df$log10.p.value, seq(0,10,2))

# Fill bars based on log10.p.value.cat
p1=ggplot(df, aes(y=log10.p.value, x=y, fill=log10.p.value.cat)) +
  geom_bar(stat="identity", width=0.2) +
  scale_y_continuous(limits=c(0,10)) +
  theme(axis.text=element_text(size=10)) +
  coord_flip()
```

The plot below is the one in your question with the legend included. Note that the ordering of the colors in `scale_fill_manual` has to match the order of the corresponding values in `log10.p.value.cat` in order to get the desired color for each category.

```
# Fill bars based on log10.p.value.cat with custom colors
p1a=ggplot(df, aes(y=log10.p.value, x=y, fill=log10.p.value.cat)) +
  geom_bar(stat="identity", width=0.2) +
  scale_y_continuous(limits=c(0,10)) +
  theme(axis.text=element_text(size=10)) +
  coord_flip() +
  scale_fill_manual(values=c("#E0E0FF","#EBCCD6","#E09898","#C74747","#B20000"))

# Continuous fill gradient based on log10.p.value
p2=ggplot(df, aes(y=log10.p.value, x=y, fill=log10.p.value)) +
  geom_bar(stat="identity", width=0.2) +
  scale_y_continuous(limits=c(0,10)) +
  theme(axis.text=element_text(size=10)) +
  coord_flip()

# Continuous fill gradient based on log10.p.value with custom colors
p2a=ggplot(df, aes(y=log10.p.value, x=y, fill=log10.p.value)) +
  geom_bar(stat="identity", width=0.2) +
  scale_y_continuous(limits=c(0,10)) +
  theme(axis.text=element_text(size=10)) +
  coord_flip() +
  scale_fill_gradientn(colours=c("#EBCCD6","#E09898","#C74747","#B20000","#E0E0FF"),
                       breaks=seq(0,10,2))
```

[image]

Comment: Thanks a lot eipi10.  I used scale_fill_manual so bar colors in the plot match their values in the data.frame. So how do I get that right in addition to the legend fill?

Comment: For plot `p1a` set the colors to be `scale_fill_manual(values=c("#E0E0FF","#EBCCD6","#E09898","#C74747","#B20000"))`. The key is to put the colors in the same order as that of the corresponding categories of `log10.p.value.cat`. Since `log10.p.value.cat` is a factor, you can get the category order from `levels(df$log10.p.value.cat)`. I've updated my answer accordingly.